# Unfortunately my app stopped working?

Tags: java, android, fonts, textview, typeface

I tried to display "hello world !" by designing an app using a custom font stored in src/Main/CustomF/times.ttf in my laptop.....while execution it disappears very soon telling that "unfortunately your app stopped"....my coding is as below.....please help me..

```
package com.example.nambimanavalan.customfonts;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView t;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mine);
        Typeface custom=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"CustomF/times.ttf");
        t.setTypeface(custom);

    }
}
```

Comment: Show stack trace -_-

Comment: can you show some logcat or stacktrace ?

Comment: Post your stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

you need to put your font in assets/Font folder and than you can use

```
 Typeface custom=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Font/times.ttf");
```

Comment: And put your fontfile in 'Font' folder inside asset folder in your project

Answer (score 0):

put your custom font in : assets/CustomF/times.ttf and maybe then it will work

assets folder is directly under your project folder, and whenever you create a fresh project it is empty.